# Pass MySQL variables to script from command line

Tags: mysql, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a MySQL update script I'd like to run from the command line, but I want to be able to pass a stage domain variable to the script.

I know this won't work, but it's the best way I can describe what I'm trying to do:

```
$ -uroot -hlocalhost mydatabase  --execute "SET @domain = 'mydomain.dev' " < ./sql/update_domain.sql
```

Inside the script, I'm using the @domain variable, to update some configuration variables in a config table, using commands like this:

```
UPDATE my_cfg SET value = @domain WHERE name = 'DOMAIN';
```

Basically I want to prefix the SET @domain on the update_domain.sql file.

Any ideas how I can rectify my approach?

Answer (score 12):

In your BATCH File :

```
mysql -e "set @domain=PARAMVALUE;source ./sql/update_domain.sql"
```

And in you SQL file :

```
UPDATE my_cfg SET value = @domain WHERE name = 'DOMAIN';
```

Comment: I get a syntax error unless I put a semicolon after the source command

Comment: It looks like this may not work in mysql 5.6 ?  `source` works interactively, but doesn't seem to work when passed in the `-e` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

you can do that with `sed` like this:

```
echo "UPDATE my_cfg SET value = '#domain#' WHERE name = 'DOMAIN'" | sed 's/#domain#/mydomain.dev/' | mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname
```

or update.sql has `UPDATE`:

```
cat update.sql | sed 's/#domain#/mydomain.dev/' | mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname
```

Comment: And of course, in case of a sh script, use double quote in the sed part to pass the new value as variable. i.e. `cat update.sql | sed "s/#domain#/$some_var/" | mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
system("(echo \"SET @domain = 'newstore.personera.abc';\"; cat sql/set_domain.sql) > /tmp/_tmp.sql")
system("mysql -uroot -hlocalhost newstore.personera.dev < /tmp/_tmp.sql")
system("rm /tmp/_tmp.sql")
```

...calling with system() from Capistrano.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a better solution.

> --init-command=name SQL Command to execute when connecting to MariaDB server.

```
mysql --init-command="SET @foo = 1; SET @bar = 2" -e "SELECT @foo, @bar, VERSION()"
```

Output:

```
+------+------+-------------------------------------+
| @foo | @bar | VERSION()                           |
+------+------+-------------------------------------+
|    1 |    2 | 10.6.3-MariaDB-1:10.6.3+maria~focal |
+------+------+-------------------------------------+
```

It also works with file redirection.