# skip-column-names not working for a call inside script

Tags: mysql-cli

I have a stored procedure `myProc` defined within a file `stored_proc.sql` that has select statements to report on various things.

If call `myProc` within `stored_proc.sql`, `skip-column-names` works.

I'd like to call `myProc` within another file `overall.sql`, but, if I do `SOURCE stored_proc.sql` and `CALL myProc()` within `overall.sql`, `skip-column-names` stops working.

I'm executing `overall.sql` like this:

`mysql <connection properties> --skip-column-names -e "SOURCE overall.sql"`

Comment: Please show how you execute the sql files and where you provide the skip column names option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `--skip-column-names` may not work with the `-e` option, but `-skip-column-names` does work, if the `*.sql` file's pipe through either through `|` or `<` (e.g. `cat overall.sql | mysql <...> --skip-column-names`). I was hoping to use `-e` to be able to set a session variable, but doing a `sed` replacement (like in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145367/pass-mysql-variables-to-script-from-command-line)) also works.